# Extra support for characters when pinging in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, ping

Currently, the rule is that if there's a single character of punctuation after a username in a mention, that user will be pinged. So for example: `@Second, @Second! @Second.` would all ping me, while `@Second!! @Second... @Second's` won't.

I'd like to propose the following:

- `@Nickname's` should ping.
- `@Nickname-kun` should ping.
- `@Nickname...` should probably ping.
- `@Nickname!!!` should probably ping.

It's awkward to say "have a look at @Second 's code" just to get the ping through.

Comment: How about anything from an `@` symbol to one of `<space>`, `.`, `,`, `!`, `?`, `'`, or `-`?

Comment: Sounds good to me, but there's probably a reason we aren't aware of which made them not do that in the first place.